# What does Chef::Log.info do exactly

Tags: logging, chef-infra

I'm trying to add some logging to my Chef recipe.

In other recipes I noticed use of `Chef::Log.info`, for example:

```
Chef::Log.info("Connection to database '#{dbname}' on '#{host}' failed")
```

I was wondering what this does. The logging does not appear anywhere it seems, not in console, not in log files. Chef website also does not seem to document why and how this should be used.

Why would you want to add such a info log statement? Where can you see such messages? Does this require a premium feature?

My `knife.rb` has log_level as follows

```
log_level                :info
log_location             STDOUT
```

Answer (score 18):

You can set the log level of your chef run by setting the `-l` flag.  So:

```
chef-client -l info
```

will result in your info log messages appearing.  Also, beware that there are two ways to do a log message. One, the method you show, will result in the message appearing during the resource gathering stage of the chef run; the other, shown below, will result in the log message appearing during the provider execution phase.

```
log 'my log messsage' do
  level :info
end
```

Comment: The second options works for me. I can see that message appear in the console. The first does not appear anywhere. I expected it to appear in console too based on knife.rb config

Comment: Have you checked to see if it appears near the top of the chef run?  That is where I would expect it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the info during the chef-client or during bootstrap simple puts statement does the work.

```
puts ("Connection to database '#{dbname}' on '#{host}' failed")
```

as `Chef::log.info` works only when you run `chef-client -l info`.

Comment: @wscourge: puts is not a right option as it will not print the messages in cronological order. while running any knife commands use -VV as it will give verbosity and also you can use debug methods. You can refer the same at Chef docs. https://docs.chef.io/debug.html

Comment: > as Chef::log.info works only when you run chef-client -l info.
i think its Chef::Log::info